# jquery chosen plugin - add display none fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

I'm using the jquery chosen plugin for Multi Select. My select looks like this :

```
<select data-placeholder="chose a friend" class="chosen-select" multiple>

    <?php   

        foreach ($my_friends as $key => $value) {

            echo '<option class="friend_firstname">'.$value["name"].'</option>';        

        }

    ?>  

</select>
```

which works perfectly, the plugin returns :

```
<ul class="chosen-choices">
    <li class="search-choice">
        <span>John</span>
        <a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="1"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My problem is that I would like to add additional information with display none to have something like :

```
<ul class="chosen-choices">
    <li class="search-choice">
        <span>John</span>
        <span style="display:none" id="user_id">678</span>
        <a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="1"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here I'm lost. How can I add additional information in display none?

Thanks for your help

Comment: why do you need a hidden field like that ? I am asking because I believe there are better ways to do such things

Comment: it's just a form to send a message, the user select a person with the real name, but then I need the id for my sql query

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a form submit, name attribute should be present for the value to be submitted. Also add value to option elements like this

```
<select name="friend" data-placeholder="chose a friend" class="chosen-select" multiple>
  <?php   
    foreach ($my_friends as $key => $value) {
      echo '<option class="friend_firstname" value="'.$value["id"].'">'.$value["name"].'</option>';        
    }
  ?>  
</select>
```

If the form is submitted the data will be submitted in the form of an array (if multiple items are selected from chosen).

Here is a sample

```js
$(".chzn-select").chosen();
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).serialize());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="/echo/json">
  <select data-placeholder="Choose a friend..." class="chzn-select" multiple style="width:350px;" name="friend">
    <option value="id1">Friend1</option>
    <option value="id2">Friend2</option>
    <option value="id3">Friend3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for you answer but I still don't see how to add the id in display none

Comment: In my example I just mentioned the id but the truth is that  I have other additional informations that I want to have in display none.

Comment: and then I manipulate those data in display none with some javascript and do things with those

Comment: see the updated answer. You don't need a hidden field to store ID.

Comment: I tried your solution but it when chosing someone the plugin generates   <ul class="chosen-choices"><li class="search-choice"><span>Peter</span><a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="0"></a></li><li class="search-field"><input type="text" value="chose a friend" class="" autocomplete="off" style="width: 25px;"></li></ul>       with no id